# ExtJS. Get images from database

Tags: c#, extjs

My image viewer :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/5.1.0/build/packages/ext-theme-classic/build/resources/ext-theme-classic-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/5.1.0/build/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/5.1.0/build/packages/ext-theme-classic/build/ext-theme-classic.js"></script>

    <style>
        .thumbnail {
            padding: 4px;
            background-color: #e6e6e0;
            border: 1px solid #d6d6d0;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>

      Ext.define('Image', {
          extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
          fields: [
              { name: 'href', type: 'string' },
              { name: 'caption', type: 'string' }
          ]
      });

  var imagesStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
          id: 'imagesStore',
          model: 'Image',
          data: [
              { href: 'images/Hydrangeas.jpg',  caption: 'Hydrangeas' },
              { href: 'images/Jellyfish.jpg', caption: 'Jellyfish' },
              { href: 'images/Koala.jpg', caption: 'Koala' },
              { href: 'images/Lighthouse.jpg', caption: 'Lighthouse' }
          ]
      });

      var imageTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
          '<tpl for=".">',
              '<div class="thumbnail" onClick="javascript:openWindow(this.lightbox);" >',
                '<img src="{href}" width="200px" height="150px" />',
                '<br/><span>{caption}</span>',
              '</div>',
          '</tpl>'
      );

      var sel_thumb_id = 0;

      var thumbs = Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
          id: 'thumbs',
          store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('imagesStore'),
          tpl: imageTpl,
          itemSelector: 'img',
          emptyText: 'No images available',
          renderTo: document.body,
          listeners: {

          }
      });

      var img = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
          id:'img',
          src: '',

          shrinkWrap: true
      });

      var next = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
          xtype: 'button',
          text: 'Next',
          width: 100,
          handler: function () {

              if (img_id < imagesStore.data.items.length ) {
              img_id = img_id + 1;
              var nextSrc = imagesStore.data.items[img_id].data.href;
              console.log(nextSrc);
              Ext.getCmp('img').setSrc(nextSrc);

                }
          }
      });

      var previous = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
          xtype: 'button',
          text: 'Previous',
          width: 100,
          handler: function () {

              if (img_id > 0) {

                  img_id = img_id - 1;
                  var nextSrc = imagesStore.data.items[img_id].data.href;
                  Ext.getCmp('img').setSrc(nextSrc);
              }
              }
      });

      var lightbox = new Ext.window.Window( {
          id: 'lightbox',
          title: '',
          height: 600,
          width: 800,
          layout: 'fit',
          items: [img],
          modal: true,
          draggable: false,
          dockedItems: [{
              xtype: 'toolbar',
              dock: 'bottom',
              padding: '5 20',
              align: 'center',
              items: [previous, next]
          }],
          closeAction: 'hide',
          resizable: false
      })

      function openWindow(lightbox) {

          img.setSrc('images/Hydrangeas.jpg');
          Ext.getCmp('lightbox').show();
          img_id = 0;
      }

  </script>
</body>
```

In this way, images are stored in a folder. Now i want to load images from database. I don't mean image path from database, i mean image. I can get images data from database using c# asmx web service.
1) What type should i choose to store images in ms sql ?
2) How can i convert data that i will get from database and display as images ?

Comment: Your question is too broad, you should show what you have tried already and what issues your facing. it may be worth reviewing the [question quidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This sounds more like a specification than a question? What have *you* done so far?

Comment: More information about your problem could be helpful. If you wanna load images from the database, store the image paths in it, that's the first thing that comes to me with the information you provide.